# What is the most elegant way to predict this set of fixed outcomes?

Tags: java

Let's say you have a fixed set of outcomes like in this image:

[image: outcomes]

The column numbers represent the four stages that will occur.
Each row is a possible outcome for the four stages.

For example: If the first stage is PURPLE and the second stage is ORANGE, the third will be BLUE and the fourth will be RED.

I've been able to do this through a quite convoluted string of if/else statements but I was wondering if there is a better way?

EDIT: The prediction must be made after the first stage and should return two possibilities for the second stage.

Comment: A lookup table seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have a 6x4 array of colors, and do a quick loop to find the row that matches the first two colors you have. Looping through six rows checking the values of the first two entries in an array is not going to be complicated code or a performance concern.

Comment: I've ended up using this approach as it is simple to implement into the current project and allowed for output of two possibilities for stage two, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the third and fourth based on the first and second, just build a map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("BR", "OP");
map.put("BP", "RO");
// ...
```

where `B`, `R`, `O` and `P` represent blue, red, orange and purple respectively. Then you can just query this, e.g.

```
String thirdAndFourth = map.get("BP");
```

Note that some other structure may be better than a string, e.g.

```
class ColorPair {
  Color first;
  Color second;
}
```

But the idea is the same:

```
Map<ColorPair, ColorPair> map = new HashMap<>();
// Populate map...

ColorPair thirdAndFourth = map.get(firstAndSecond);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a recursive approach with prestoring outcomes,
Call setup() before starting the processing of input.

```
// Pre known outcomes
List<String> outcomes;
// To track the inputs as we move on through them
public static StringBuilder inputStore = new StringBuilder();
// To track no of inputs expected overall
public static int counter = 0;
// Method for processing next input recursively
public static void next(int input){
    // Appending is to track each input
    inputStore.append(input);
    counter++;
    if(counter == noOfInputsExpected){
        // Process inputStore
        String s1 = inputStore.toString();
        for(String s : outcomes){
            // Check if the inputs collected match the defined ones
            if(s.equals(s1))
                //Process outcome
        }
        return;
    }
    else if(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4){
        // In case of valid input move on
        // We can even separate each one as a else for mid step processing
        next(getNextInput());
    }
    else{
        // Bad input, take some action
    }
}

public static void setup(){

    // Assuming inputs, are {1234, 1324, ... some permutations in you know}
    outcomes = new ArrayList<String>(noOfPermutationsRequired);
    //Put all the known possibilities
    ...
    outcomes.add("1234");
    outcomes.add("1324");
    ...
}
```